# Searching for a specific series of novels about a post apocalyptic war with vampires and human magic users

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I started reading the first book in this series a few years ago, about 2015, and am in the mood to re-read and then finish the series, but have completely forgotten the title of both the book and the series as well as the author's name.

The book had already been published for a couple of years and at the time of initial reading I think there were three books in total in the series, though I am unsure on that.

The book setting was in a post apocalyptic world where humans fought vampires. It was fairly grim dark in tone. I think the vampires had bone cities, the humans iron ones and that there were plains of salt between where the two skirmished. The main protagonist was a young male soldier who I think used a glove like device to perform magic.

I am pretty sure I remember an early scene in the book where there was a patrol killed in some sort of storm or fog.

It's more like *[V-Wars](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13498652-v-wars)* by Jonathan Maberry in tone and theme than it is like James Khan's *[New World](https://www.goodreads.com/series/102155-new-world-trilogy)* series

---

It is not *[The Passage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Passage_(Cronin_novel))* by Justin Cronin.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anymore details you may remember?

Comment: I'm thinking James Khan's New World series- "World Enough, And Time", "Time's Dark laughter" and "Timefall". The second book is closest to the description.

Comment: Hi Covertwalrus.  Thanks for taking a stab.  I had a look and that's not it.  Thank you though.  I have been looking around a bit more...in vain...but can conclude it's more like V Wars by Jonathan Maberry in tone and theme.  Thanks again everyone...still holding out hope. 